# How to move files with find and head

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I am trying to find any random 1 file and move to a different location using commandline.
The following command displays the file,

> `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[!.]*' | head -n 1`

Now i am trying to use it to move the file to a different location eg /home/etl in the given example. However I am getting the error head: invalid option -- 'e'

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[!.]*' | head -n 1 -exec mv {} /home/etl
```

Could you please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

The find command ends with the pipe symbol | so you can't continue to use the -exec which is a find parameter behind that. You can use xargs to do something similar.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[!.]*' | head -n 1 |xargs -I'{}' mv {} /home/etl
```